# How to properly create explicit argument-forwarding function with variadic templates in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm working on a class that lets you dynamically register types with a common base type to keys, then dynamically construct instances of that type based on key. Here's what it looks like right now:

```
template<class Key, class Base>
class TypeRegistry
{
private:
    FunctionRegistry<Key, Base*> m_registry;

    template<class Derived>
    static Base* make()
    {
        return new Derived();
    }

public:
    template<class Derived>
    void register_type(const Key& key)
    {
        m_registry.register_function(key, &make<Derived>);
    }

    Base* make_type(const Key& key) const
    {
        auto maker = m_registry.get_function(key);
        if(maker) return maker();
        else return nullptr;
    }
};
```

The `FunctionRegistry` class has this interface:

```
template<class Key, class Ret, class... Args>
class FunctionRegistry
{
public:
    typedef Ret (*function_type)(Args...);

    //register a key and function pointer
    void register_function(const Key& key, function_type func);

    //get a function pointer, or nullptr if the key is not registered
    function_type get_function(const Key& key) const;
};
```

Now, my question is about extending TypeRegistry to support constructor arguments, using a variadic template. I don't know I should do the TypeRegistry::make function. Here's what I'm hoping for:

```
template<class Key, class Base, class... ConstructorArgs>
class TypeRegistry
{
private:
    FunctionRegistry<Key, Base*, ConstructorArgs...> m_registry;

    template<class Derived, ???>
    static Base* make(???)
    {
        return new Derived(???);
    }

public:
    template<class Derived>
    void register_type(const Key& key)
    {
        m_registry.register_function(key, &make<Derived, ???>);
    }

    template<class... DeterminedArgs>
    Base* make_type(const Key& key, DeterminedArgs&&... args) const
    {
        auto maker = m_registry.get_function(key);
        if(maker) return maker(std::forward<DeterminedArgs>(args)...);
        else return nullptr;
    }
};
```

The trouble is, I don't know how to properly template the make() function. Presumably it has to just be take `ConstructorArgs...` as its arguments, so that it can be properly registered in the `FunctionRegistry`, but then how do I make sure that all the arguments are properly forwarded (rvalue vs lvalue) to the `Derived` constructor?

Comment: have you heard of perfect forwarding?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it it make_type. The trouble is that it isn't clear how to do perfect forwarding when you have to explicitly instantiate the function template (as in `register_type`), as opposed to when the compiler does it for you (as in `make_type`)

Comment: Perfect forwarding needs template argument deduction, and there are no function-pointer templates.

Comment: So every one of your registered types are constructed with the exact same arguments?

Comment: That's a requirement, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't put the definition of FunctionRegistry, I could not test it. Now I created the real example (which compiles) and where I fixed the issues. One of the biggest issue is that you tried to pass pointer to member function to a function pointer. For that reason, you must make the `TypeRegistry::make` a static method.

So, here is it :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct Abase
{
    virtual ~Abase(){}
    virtual void bar()=0;
};
struct A : Abase
{
    A(int g,float h) : Abase(), a(g),b(h)
    {
    }
    virtual ~A(){}

    virtual void bar()
    {
        std::cout<<a<<b<<std::endl;
    }
    int a;float b;
};
Abase* foo(int&& v,float&& b)
{
    return new A(v,b);
}

template<class Key, class Ret, class... Args>
class FunctionRegistry
{
public:
    typedef Ret (*function_type)(Args...);

    //register a key and function pointer
    void register_function(const Key& key, function_type func)
    {}

    //get a function pointer, or nullptr if the key is not registered
    function_type get_function(const Key& key) const
    {
        (void)key;
        return foo;
    }
};

template<class Key, class Base, class... ConstructorArgs>
class TypeRegistry
{
private:
    FunctionRegistry<Key, Base*, ConstructorArgs&&...> m_registry;

    template<class Derived>
    static Base* make(ConstructorArgs&&... args)
    {
        return new Derived(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...);
    }

public:
    template<class Derived>
    void register_type(const Key& key)
    {
        m_registry.register_function(key, &make<Derived> );
    }

    Base* make_type(const Key& key, ConstructorArgs&&... args) const
    {
        auto maker = m_registry.get_function(key);
        if(maker) return maker(std::forward<ConstructorArgs>(args)...);
        else return nullptr;
    }
};


int main()
{
    TypeRegistry< int, Abase, int, float > tr;

    tr.register_type< A >( 5 );

    auto a = tr.make_type( 5, 3, 5.3f );
    a->bar();
}
```